# Checkbox not getting ticked or untick when list of selected check box is deleted in Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a Json object which i use to display checkboxes using ngFor angular 7 directive,on selecting any of the checkboxes the values of labels are displayed on same page with provision of delete each value from this list but the list is not updating when deleting values.
Code is attached,thanks for help in advance.

my ts file

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkboxexample',
  templateUrl: './checkboxexample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkboxexample.component.scss']
})
export class CheckboxexampleComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedItemsList = [];
  checkedIDs = [];

  checkboxesDataList = [
    {
      id: 'C001',
      label: 'Photography',
      isChecked: true
    },
    {
      id: 'C002',
      label: 'Writing',
      isChecked: true
    },
    {
      id: 'C003',
      label: 'Painting',
      isChecked: true
    },
    {
      id: 'C004',
      label: 'Knitting',
      isChecked: false
    },
    {
      id: 'C004',
      label: 'Dancing',
      isChecked: false
    },
    {
      id: 'C005',
      label: 'Gardening',
      isChecked: true
    },
    {
      id: 'C006',
      label: 'Drawing',
      isChecked: true
    },
    {
      id: 'C007',
      label: 'Gyming',
      isChecked: false
    },
    {
      id: 'C008',
      label: 'Cooking',
      isChecked: true
    },
    {
      id: 'C009',
      label: 'Scrapbooking',
      isChecked: false
    },
    {
      id: 'C010',
      label: 'Origami',
      isChecked: false
    }
  ]

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchSelectedItems()
    this.fetchCheckedIDs()
  }

  changeSelection() {
    this.fetchSelectedItems()

  }

  fetchSelectedItems() {
    this.selectedItemsList = this.checkboxesDataList.filter((value, index) => {
      return value.isChecked
    });
  }

  fetchCheckedIDs() {
    this.checkedIDs = []
    this.checkboxesDataList.forEach((value, index) => {
      if (value.isChecked) {
        this.checkedIDs.push(value.id);
      }
    });
  }
  deleteTodo(id: number): void {
    this.selectedItemsList = this.selectedItemsList.filter(item => item.id !== id);
  }
}
```

related html file

```
    <h1>Checklist</h1>
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>List of Hobbies</h4>

        <ul class="checkbox-items">
            <li *ngFor="let item of checkboxesDataList">
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" [(ngModel)]="item.isChecked"
                    (change)="changeSelection()">{{item.label}}
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>No of Selected Hobbies: {{selectedItemsList.length}} </h4>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of selectedItemsList">{{item.label}}
                <div class="remove-item" (click)="deleteTodo(item.id)">
                    &times;
                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>Object</h4>
        <code>
    {{selectedItemsList | json}}
    </code>

        <h4>Array of IDs</h4>
        <code>{{checkedIDs}}</code>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `trackBy` to resolve this - [see docs](https://angular.io/api/core/TrackByFunction)

should looks something like the following (in the html):

```
    <li *ngFor="let item of checkboxesDataList; trackBy: trackById">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" [(ngModel)]="item.isChecked"
            (change)="changeSelection()">{{item.label}}
    </li>
```

in in your component:

```
trackById(item: {id: string}) {
    return item.id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help issue is solved by Rajat

Answer (score 1):

id being passed to deleteTodo method should be string.

```
deleteTodo(id: string): void {
    this.selectedItemsList = this.selectedItemsList.filter(item => item.id !== id);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help issue is solved by Rajat

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to update the checkboxesDataList on deletion.
Please find the working code below.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s468tm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Just update following method:

```
deleteTodo(id: number): void {
    
    this.selectedItemsList = this.selectedItemsList.filter(
      item => item.id !== id
    );
    this.checkboxesDataList.forEach(element => {
      if (element.id == id.toString()) {
        element.isChecked = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: the stackblitz you have shared is empty,please provide the code..thanks in advance

Comment: Simply brilliant Rajat,a million thanks to you..it worked like wonder..

Comment: Hi i had another issue, I wanted to enhance the functionality of this,can u please look at it i have posted it on: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65198170/6721202