# How to add Multiple filter for a list and uncheck them individually in angular 7?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a checkbox list populated using ngFor in Angular 7 and 3 buttons to filter the checkbox list,I am able to filter only once currently.What i want to do it to add multiple filters like if i click complted button i should also be allowed to click Active and any other button and the list should filter only those.Lastly i should be allowed to undo the filters on its clicks as well.THANKS A LOT IN ADVANCE.
My code is below:

My ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkboxexample',
  templateUrl: './checkboxexample.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkboxexample.component.scss']
})
export class CheckboxexampleComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedItemsList = [];
  checkedIDs = [];
  filter: string;
  num1: any;



  checkboxesDataList = [
    {
      id: 'C001',
      label: 'Photography',
      isChecked: false,
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 'C002',
      label: 'Writing',
      isChecked: false,
      completed: true
    },
    {
      id: 'C003',
      label: 'Painting',
      isChecked: false,
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 'C004',
      label: 'Knitting',
      isChecked: false,
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 'C011',
      label: 'Dancing',
      isChecked: false,
      completed: true
    },
    {
      id: 'C005',
      label: 'Gardening',
      isChecked: false,
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 'C006',
      label: 'Drawing',
      isChecked: false,
      completed: true
    },
    {
      id: 'C007',
      label: 'Gyming',
      isChecked: false,
      completed: true
    },
    {
      id: 'C008',
      label: 'Cooking',
      isChecked: false,
      completed: true
    },
    {
      id: 'C009',
      label: 'Scrapbooking',
      isChecked: false,
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: 'C010',
      label: 'Origami',
      isChecked: false,
      completed: false
    }
  ]

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('screening') != null) {
      this.selectedItemsList = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('screening'));
      this.checkboxesDataList = this.selectedItemsList
      this.num1 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('manual'))
    }
    this.filter = 'all';
    this.fetchSelectedItems()
    this.fetchCheckedIDs()

  }

  changeSelection() {
    this.fetchSelectedItems()

  }

  fetchSelectedItems() {
    this.selectedItemsList = this.checkboxesDataList.filter((value, index) => {

      return value.isChecked
    });
  }

  fetchCheckedIDs() {
    this.checkedIDs = []
    this.checkboxesDataList.forEach((value, index) => {
      if (value.isChecked) {
        this.checkedIDs.push(value.id);
      }
    });
  }
  deleteTodo(id: string): void {
    this.selectedItemsList = this.selectedItemsList.filter(item => item.id !== id);
    this.checkboxesDataList.forEach(element => {
      if (element.id == id.toString()) {
        element.isChecked = false;
      }
    });
  }
  onsubmit() {
    this.num1 = ((document.getElementById("manual") as HTMLInputElement).value);
    sessionStorage.setItem('manual', JSON.stringify(this.num1));
    sessionStorage.setItem('screening', JSON.stringify(this.checkboxesDataList))
  }
  todosFiltered() {
    if (this.filter === 'all') {
      return this.checkboxesDataList;
    } else if (this.filter === 'editing') {
      return this.checkboxesDataList.filter(todo => !todo.completed);
    } else if (this.filter === 'completed') {
      return this.checkboxesDataList.filter(todo => todo.completed);
    }

    return this.checkboxesDataList;
  }

}
```

My html file

```
<h1>Checklist</h1>
<div class="extra-container">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;padding-left: 2%;">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item"><button [ngClass]="{'active': filter === 'all'}"
                    (click)="filter='all'">All</button></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><button [ngClass]="{'active': filter === 'editing'}"
                    (click)="filter='editing'">Active</button></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><button [ngClass]="{'active': filter === 'completed'}"
                    (click)="filter='completed'">Completed</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4>List of Hobbies</h4>



            <ul class="checkbox-items">
                <li *ngFor="let item of todosFiltered().slice(0,7)">

                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" [(ngModel)]="item.isChecked"
                        (change)="changeSelection()">{{item.label}}

                </li>
                <li *ngFor="let item of todosFiltered().slice(7,14)">

                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" [(ngModel)]="item.isChecked"
                        (change)="changeSelection()">{{item.label}}

                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4>No of Selected Hobbies: {{selectedItemsList.length}}
                <input type="text" id="manual" value={{num1}}> </h4>
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let item of selectedItemsList">{{item.label}}
                    <div class="remove-item" (click)="deleteTodo(item.id)">
                        &times;
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4>Object</h4>
            <code>
    {{selectedItemsList | json}} 
    </code>

            <h4>Array of IDs</h4>
            <code>{{checkedIDs}}</code>
        </div>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" (click)="onsubmit()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Please describe in detail the filter thing. Like if there is Active filter clicked and now you click on completed filter You want to filter from list of Active filter values ? Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: In the above code i have 3 buttons on whos click i am getting the filtered list but what i want is when i click on any button Like for example i click on Active then Completed, i should have a list which has active and completed filtered and if i click the button again it should undo the filter applied to that button. In short it should work as check boxes.

Comment: Hope i was able to explain better

Comment: Here is the stackblitz link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s468tm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply multiple filters, I would make each toggle update its own filter state. Then you could apply multiple filters to your array and return the result. Your filter method would look something like:

```
todosFiltered() {
    let checkboxesToDisplay = this.checkboxesDataList;

    if (this.filterActive) {
      checkboxesToDisplay = checkboxesToDisplay.filter(todo => !todo.completed);
    }

    if (this.filterCompleted) {
      checkboxesToDisplay = checkboxesToDisplay.filter(todo => todo.completed);
    }

    return checkboxesToDisplay;
  }
```

Then each button could toggle those filters and the 'All' button could set them to false.

```
<li class="list-group-item"><button [ngClass]="{'active': filter === 'all'}"
                    (click)="filterActive=false;filterCompleted=false">All</button></li>
<li class="list-group-item"><button [ngClass]="{'active': filter === 'editing'}"
                    (click)="filterActive=!filterActive">Active</button></li>
<li class="list-group-item"><button [ngClass]="{'active': filter === 'completed'}"
                    (click)="filterCompleted=!filterCompleted">Completed</button></li>
```

I made some quick changes that should get you closer to the behavior you are looking for:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rmqdjn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Updated the @robbieAreBest Stackblitz for covering all your scenarios

Comment: yes it is close to it but what i am looking for is when i have a json: {
      id: "C001",
      label: "Photography",
      isChecked: false,
      completed: false,
      mri: true,
      colonoscopy:true
    }    and i have buttons like mri,colonoscopy  and when i click on mri  and colonoscopy i want all the checkboxes that has mri,colonoscopy which is set to true in json  to display. LIke if i have 5 checkboxes whos mri is true and 4 checkboxes whos colonoscopy is true so final will be 9 in the list

Comment: Your data is not good for that. Since currently, you basic filtering is done based on todo.completed. You should rather apply filtering based on labels in your data